# Can Spring Cloud Gateway route to AWS SNS/SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, spring-cloud-gateway

We implemented push api using spring cloud gateway/spring boot (Spring Boot 2.X) and able to successfully able to route to different **external** customer endpoints. The app is deployed on AWS EKS.

Now a new external customer would like us to **POST** JSON to a AWS SNS/SQS so that they can consume at their own space and can also manage any downtime etc.

Yet to explore way to do so (would like to avoid any use of filters).

Appreciate any suggestions

Comment: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.0.0.RELEASE/multi/multi__messaging.html